# cannot find symbol with isLowerCase

Tags: java, character

I took this code directly out of Thinking in java 4th edition and it keeps giving me 'cannot find symbol: method isLowerCase(Char). Is the book wrong, do I maybe not have the character class with all my files, or am I doing a really really really stupid mistake?

```
public class ListCharacters{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(char c = 0; c < 128; c++)
            if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
                System.out.println("value:"+(int)c+ " character: " + c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing `java.lang`?

Comment: It doesn't say to in the example. And I've seen other examples online where they don't have to import.

Comment: java.lang is imported implicitly. You should never have to import a class in the java.lang package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a class called `Character` in the same folder as your `ListCharacters` class?

On its own, your `ListCharacters` class compiled fine for me.  However, when I added a class called `Character` to the same folder, I got a 'cannot find symbol' error for the `isLowerCase` method.

Comment: yes! o thank you! it was from another program I made! i'm learning new stuff every day here. thanks a lot person!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the name of the method or how it's been used, so I'm afraid it does suggest your Java installation has a problem. What version of the JDK have you installed? As far as I can tell isLowerCase() has always been there so I'm not quite sure what could be wrong. Are you compiling from a plain text file using the command-line Java compiler, or using an IDE such as Eclipse? It might be that if you're using an IDE then you haven't pointed it to the correct version of Java.

Comment: I have ijava 7 installed and I'm just putting code in notepad and just compiling with javac from the command prompt. I guess I'll redownload it.

Comment: Actually, check Cory's suggestion first - I was a bit hasty.